# How do I execute functions relative to the time?

Tags: swift, function, swift2

I'm having trouble writing code that will execute a function based on the current time and name of the day(Example, Sunday 4 pm). I've posted my code below and BTW I'm rather new to this. I know if statements are "lazy" and once one condition is met it executes the statement and doesn't execute the rest.

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)

let year =  components.year
let month = components.month
let day = components.day

let componentFHM = calendar.components([ .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)
let hour = componentFHM.hour
let minute = componentFHM.minute


let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
let dayOfWeekString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
print(dayOfWeekString)



if week[0] == dayOfWeekString {
    if hour > 0 {
        print("hello")
    }
       } else if week[6] == dayOfWeekString {
           print("hello2")
              }else{
    print("Hello3")
}

if hour >= 9{
   // if minute >= 0{
        if minute >= 30{
            if hour <= 18{
                //if minute >= 0{
                    if minute <= 30{
                print("Hello")
        //I would put the function here.


                    }
                }
            }


}else if hour <= 0{
    //if minute >= 0{
        if minute <= 0{
            if hour <= 0{
              //  if minute >= 0{
                    if minute >= 0{
                        print("HelloWorld")


                }
            }
        }

}else{print("Hello Mac")}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to create a code outline for my function to execute during a certain time on a certain day and I'm stumped. For example, execute function at 12 pm - 3pm on Tuesday.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switch statement:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components([ .Weekday, .Hour, .Minute], fromDate: NSDate())

switch ( components.weekday, components.hour, components.minute )
{
   case ( 1,     7,       30 ) :  print("Sunday 7H30, take a coffee and do you weekly run")
   case ( 2...6, 6,       _  ) :  print("Weekdays, between 6 and 7 AM, get ready to work")
   case ( 6,     17...23, _  ) :  print("TGIF Party !!!")  
   default : break
}
```